# Jlist Custom Renderer

Tags: java, swing, jlist, renderer

I'm trying to add a i guess you would call it a sub list to each item on a list. I've built a custom renderer that gives the below output. As you can see something isn't right here an i've had no luck tracking down an answer to my problem. I'm guessing i need to change something in the layout of the panel to get the correct result but no idea what.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCKjJ.jpg

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GAListRendererAdv extends Container implements ListCellRenderer {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
private Random rnd = new Random();

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
        boolean cellHasFocus) {

    pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JCheckBox chckbxSomething = new JCheckBox("something");
    pnl.add(chckbxSomething, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
    pnl.add(separator, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 35, 0, 0));
    pnl.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel_1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

    int rndNum = rnd.nextInt(5) + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < rndNum; i ++) {
    JLabel lblNewLabel2 = new JLabel("New label");
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel2);
    }

    return pnl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, remember, `CellRenderers` are used as "rubber stamps" in Swing.  This is done to save memory and help increase performance.  This allows components, like `JList`, to maintain a single reference to the renderer but still paint all the items in the list.

This means, that when ever `getListCellRendererComponent` is called, the renderer will be in the same state it was last it was called.

From what I can tell from your code, this will mean that each time the renderer is called, you add ANOTHER checkbox, ANOTHER separator ANOTHER panel and lots more labels...

Secondly of all, with renderers, try not to create anything in the the `getListCellRendererComponent` where possible, this is just increasing you memory usage (part of your code may not have a choice).

Thirdly, `JList` does not support editors, renderers are not editors, for the reasons I've stated before.

Forthly.  Try removing the content from the "body" portion of the panel before adding all your elements to it.

```
// Don't use Container, use JPanel instead, mixing heavy and light weight components
// is never a good idea :P
public class GAListRendererAdv extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    private JCheckBox checkBox;

    public GAListRendererAdv() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));            
        checkBox = new JCheckBox();

        add(checkBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new JSeparator(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pnl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        pnl.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 35, 0, 0));

        add(pnl BorderLayout.SOUTH); // Don't forget to add the panel :P

    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        pnl.removeAll();
        int rndNum = rnd.nextInt(5) + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < rndNum; i ++) {
            JLabel lblNewLabel2 = new JLabel("New label");
            pnl.add(lblNewLabel2);
        }

        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer. You said: "Thirdly, JList does not support editors, renderers are not editors". So, here goes my question, what would you do then to show, and make a editable list (or sequence) of components?. 

Specifically I'm populating custom panes in a JList via CellRenderers, but all funcionallity (as buttons and so on) doesn't work.

Comment: The easy solution is to actually use a single column `JTable`. You can get away with not displaying the column name by overriding the `getColumnName` method of the model and returning an empty string

Comment: So @MadProgrammer, that way the table must be set with a particular implementation of TableCellEditor or am I wrong?. the custom cells rendered still don't allow buttons interaction.

Maybe better solution would be adding dinamically the components to the LayoutManager inside a ScrollPane?, I don't know how to do this but I'll mess around with it.

Comment: Well, it is much easier to use a layout manager and add the components to the container pane dinamically in this case, instead of using tables or lists or whatever. No renderers and no editors.

And then using removeAll() ---> validate(), repaint() to the container pane to change the content.