# how to create a JList of JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlist

I'm trying to build a GUI for my Java application. I have an `ArrayList` of `Jbuttons` and I want to store them in a `JList`. but I get an error of Wrong input for `JList`.
and also I have an add `Jbutton` to add new buttons to my list.

Does anyone have any advice?

```
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        ArrayList<JButton> btnList = new ArrayList<>();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        JList list = new JList();
        JButton add = new JButton("ADD");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                //add new JButtons to list
            }
        });
        panel.add(add); panel.add(list);
```

Comment: Why do you want/think you need to adding `JButton`s to a `JList`?  If you're just trying to produce a vertical stack of buttons, add them to a `JPanel` instead and apply an appropriate layout.

Comment: Add the `JButtons` into a `JPanel `with `BoxLayout`. Then add this `JPanel` into a `JScrollPane`.

Comment: Create the button in the cell renderer, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751191/jlist-custom-renderer